# I need some help installing Inkscape on Raspbian

Tags: software-installation

I am using the latest release of Raspbian and I noticed that one of my favorite apps isn't in the software center. I can't seem to find Inkscape for Raspbian. Can someone help me install it?

Comment: `apt-cache search inkscape` - inkscape definitely exists as a package

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Whenever you use Raspbian (or any other type of Debian/Ubuntu based Linux distro), there are two simple ways to install any package.

1. Download a **".deb"** package and use a GUI.
2. Open your terminal and write the installer command this way.

> **"sudo apt-get install inkscape"** [replace inkscape with any package you want to install]

It will ask for some permission and install for you.

Note: you need superuser permissions (sudo) to install a package.

Hope it helps!

Comment: It's probably worth mentioning to do a `sudo apt-get update` to make sure the repository lists are up to date.

Comment: I tried sudo apt install inkscape but it said that inkscape couldn't be found. I tried the .deb and it won't start because it needs a ton of dependencies. I don't want to download every dependency and every dependency's dependency. Can I add a repository that has Inkscape?

Answer (score 2):

In response to your comment:

> I tried sudo apt install inkscape but it said that inkscape couldn't
>   be found.

and to complete the answer from *@Rishi*, you definitely find `inkscape` in the default repositories of Raspbian. I use `Raspbian Stretch Lite 2018-03-13`. First make sure you have the default repositories addressed in the `sources.list`:

```
rpi3 ~$ cat /etc/apt/sources.list
deb http://raspbian.raspberrypi.org/raspbian/ stretch main contrib non-free rpi
# Uncomment line below then 'apt-get update' to enable 'apt-get source'
#deb-src http://raspbian.raspberrypi.org/raspbian/ stretch main contrib non-free rpi

rpi3 ~$ cat /etc/apt/sources.list.d/raspi.list
deb http://archive.raspberrypi.org/debian/ stretch main ui
# Uncomment line below then 'apt-get update' to enable 'apt-get source'
#deb-src http://archive.raspberrypi.org/debian/ stretch main ui
```

Then update Raspbian:

```
rpi3 ~$ sudo apt update
rpi3 ~$ sudo apt full-upgrade
```

Maybe reboot if you have many updates. And now you will find:

```
rpi3 ~$ apt list inkscape
Listing... Done
inkscape/stable 0.92.1-1 armhf
rpi3 ~$
```

Answer (score 0):

The version currently (November 2021) available via apt-get is old (0.92). You can get a modern version from the "snap store" (https://snapcraft.io/install/inkscape/raspbian). You can then launch it from the terminal. On my machine, a bunch of warning messages scroll by and then a perfect version of Inkscape 1.1 with all default extensions.